# how to get all taxonomy children id in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-taxonomy

I have taxonomy with 3 levels of children. I need to get all level of children by a parent tid.

taxonomy_get_children($tid) - gives a direct children of that particular $tid only. But not the all grand children.

How do I process this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

```
function taxonomy_get_children_all($tid, $vid = 0, $key = 'tid'){
    $c = taxonomy_get_children($tid, $vid, $key);
    $result = array();
    foreach ($c as $t => $d){
        $result[$t] = $d;
        $below = taxonomy_get_children_all($t, $vid, $key);
        if (!empty($below)) {
            foreach ($below as $nt => $nd){
                $result[$nt] = $nd;
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Reference: https://drupal.org/node/381952

Comment: This is very useful but any chance to do the same via SQL query ?

Answer (score 0):

Looking on https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_children/7
and 
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_children/6
You should get multiple results. What Drupal do you use ?

Comment: Using drupal 7 function (taxonomy_get_children) I can't render the all  level of children

Comment: It seems like it uses https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_load_multiple/7 which should return multiple results.

Answer (score 0):

```
$tree = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree('MACHINE_VOCABULARY_NAME');

        foreach ($tree as $term) {
             $termID[] = array(
              'termId' => $term->tid,
              'parent'=> $term->parents,
              'depth' => $term->depth
             );
        }
        dump($termID);
```